# {NodeJS} Got stupid ws error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND echo.websocket.org

Tags: node.js, websocket

I use `ws` library.

The code:

```
WebSocket = require("ws");

ws = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");
ws.onopen = function() {
    ws.send("Hello, world!");
};
ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
    console.log("Message: " + msg.data);
};
ws.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
};
ws.onclose = function() {
    console.log("Closed");
};
```

The console returns:

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND echo.websocket.org echo.websocket.org:80]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'echo.websocket.org',
  host: 'echo.websocket.org',
  port: 80,
  type: 'error',
  target:
   WebSocket {
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { open: [Object],
        message: [Object],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Object] },
     _eventsCount: 4,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _socket: null,
     _ultron: null,
     _closeReceived: false,
     bytesReceived: 0,
     readyState: 0,
     supports: { binary: true },
     extensions: {},
     _isServer: false,
     url: 'ws://echo.websocket.org',
     protocolVersion: 13 } }
```

Yesterday it worked, but today, it doesn't work. I tried reinstalling `Node.JS` and `ws`, but it didn't help. How can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like the nameserver you're using is acting up, as it can't resolve `echo.websocket.org` for whatever reason. Try this: `var ws = new WebSocket("ws://174.129.224.73", { headers : { Host : 'echo.websocket.org' } })`

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But do You know how to fix this "error"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `cmd.exe` and `ping echo.websocket.org`. Then I tried run my script again. I don't know why, but it worked. Probably it's a bug with Node.JS DNS.